# BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly [abc.dll].... Previously working fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll

I have a custom dll which is referenced to web project. When I try to launch app in Visual studio, I get the "Server Error in '/' Application". The details shows that it couldn't load file or assembly [abc.dll]. The strange thing is, I didn't have issue running the application yesterday and I don't see anything that has changed since yesterday in my project.
What could be causing this issue in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using 32 bit dll on 64 bit machine or the other way around.

Comment: the thing is, it was working yesterday and there hasnt been any such changes in 32bit vs 64 bit. I gave a shot anyway changing web project build to both x86 and x64. No luck!